# Updating a Table via SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, sum, subquery, left-join

I am using Oracle SQL and need to update the HISTORICAL field from the LOCATION table (LOCATION.HISTORICAL)  to T(True), only where there are no parts on hand in those locations from the table STOCK. The tables STOCK and LOCATION are joined by the field, LOC_AUTO_KEY. I need to update around 1400 locations, and do not wish to do it manually… need some help cleaning up my SQL Statement.

Below is what I have come up with so far. My subquery works if entered by itself, without executing the SET function. Below is my subquery, which returns only the locations that have a sum of 0 quantity on hand in the stock table:

```
SELECT LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY, LOCATION.LOCATION_CODE, Sum(STOCK.QTY_OH) AS SumOfQTY_OH, LOCATION.HISTORICAL
FROM LOCATION LEFT JOIN STOCK ON LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY = STOCK.LOC_AUTO_KEY
GROUP BY LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY, LOCATION.LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION.HISTORICAL
HAVING (((Sum(STOCK.QTY_OH))=0))
```

I attempted to add the SET to update the Location.Historical field with the following:

```
UPDATE LOCATION
SET LOCATION.HISTORICAL=T
FROM LOCATION WHERE EXISTS(SELECT LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY, LOCATION.LOCATION_CODE, Sum(STOCK.QTY_OH) AS SumOfQTY_OH, LOCATION.HISTORICAL
FROM LOCATION LEFT JOIN STOCK ON LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY = STOCK.LOC_AUTO_KEY
GROUP BY LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY, LOCATION.LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION.HISTORICAL
HAVING ((SUM(STOCK.QTY_OH)=0))
```

Received Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Please help so I do not have to update 1400 locations manually!
Thanks – K8TE

Update: I have added the closing parenthesis that Remi pointed out I was missing and am not receiving any errors. HOWEVER, all locations HISTORICAL fields are updated to 'T', instead of only those locations that have a 0 (zero) SUMQTY from STOCK. I only want locations that have 0 sum QTY on Hand to be updated. Any further help would be appreciated.

```
    UPDATE LOCATION
SET LOCATION.HISTORICAL='T' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY, LOCATION.LOCATION_CODE, Sum(STOCK.QTY_OH) AS SumOfQTY_OH, LOCATION.HISTORICAL
FROM LOCATION LEFT JOIN STOCK ON LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY = STOCK.LOC_AUTO_KEY
GROUP BY LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY, LOCATION.LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION.HISTORICAL
HAVING (((Sum(STOCK.QTY_OH))=0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a closing parenthesis. The parenthesis opened after `WHERE EXISTS` is not closed.

Update: you also need to join the subquery to the main query. Your subquery needs a `WHERE` clause to join with the LOCATION table.

Comment: I am probably wrong, but isn't that the following string in my subquery: LEFT JOIN STOCK ON LOCATION.LOC_AUTO_KEY = STOCK.LOC_AUTO_KEY?

Comment: No. You have in fact two LOCATION tables: one in each FROM. You must join them. Another possibility is to use the `IN` operator instead of `EXISTS`: `WHERE LOCATION.ID IN (SELECT LOCATION.ID ...).